# Creating arrays of swing components or specifically JTextFields and giving each of them different properties in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

So I'm trying to create a large number of `JTextField`s and use them as nodes in a binary tree program I'm trying to make. Is there a way to create an array of JTextFields, something like:

```
JTextField nodes[]=new JTextField[30];
```

If so, how do I define or give every one of them different properties or the property I want them to have?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `TextField nodes[]=new JTextField[30];` and then accessing just like an normal array ?

Comment: You can access it but if I try adding it to a panel it will give me an error. The reason is I've not defined it individually. And I'm not sure how to define it in the first place. For example setting a size for it, entering a text to it, etc.

Comment: It gives me a nullPointerException by the way

Comment: 1. use get/putClientProperty, 2. nodes in a binary tree  - you can to multiply the ClientProperty with endless number of parameters, its settable, scallable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[30];
for(int i = 0; i<fields.length; i++){
    fields = new JTextField();
}

//then you can access them and modify them as normal.
fields[3].setColumns(5);
fields[3].setText("apples");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
JTextField[] jtfs = new JTextFields[] {
    // Define as many textfields as you want
    new JTextField(), // no args
    new JTextField("Initial text"), // text
    new JTextField(20), // 20 columns
    new JTextField("Initial text", 20), // text + columns number
    ...
}
```

Comment: So if I want to lets say give nodes[3] a name of "apple" and change its size or dimension then how will that work? Can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Or am I confusing rows with columns? Columns as of size of the array in this situation?

Comment: you can select the fourth textfield like this : `nodes[3]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through all your `JTextField`s, taking this as an example you could add a `switch` inside the `for` loop to put inside each `case` the properties of each `JTextField`.

From your comments on other answers I saw you wanted `field[3]` (or any name you want) to change the columns number and have "Apple" written inside it.

Next time you should provide a [Runnable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as the one I'm providing so we can copy-paste it and give you a better approach. And (optionally) an image of what you want.

Here I used only 5 `JTextFields` to make an example, you can have the 30 you want, try it :)

The code below produces this output:

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class ArrayOfJTextField {
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel pane;
    JTextField fields[];
    ArrayOfJTextField () {
        frame = new JFrame("Frame Test");
        fields = new JTextField[5];
        Container pane2 = frame.getContentPane();
        pane2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(frame.getContentPane(), BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

        for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
            pane = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
            fields[i] = new JTextField ("This is field " + (i + 1)); //You missed to do this and that's why you were getting a NPE
            if (i == 3) {
                fields[i].setColumns(10);
                fields[i].setText("Apple");
            } else {
                fields[i].setColumns(5);
            }
            pane.add(new JLabel("Label " + (i +1)));
            pane.add(fields[i]);
            frame.add(pane);
        }

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        new ArrayOfJTextField();
    }
}
```